# Dependable dropdown in inline row editing in 2 ag grid cell

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I started implementing ag grid in angular. Everything is good in listing. But for inline full row editing I am facing 2 issues.

1. I have 2 cells having dropdown. I am using custom cell editor component for each dropdown cell. now I want that If I change the value of dropdown in first cell then it should change the dropdown data in second cell.
2. I have an action column. having edit button. So When I click on edit, I hide the edit button and show save and cancel button and call this function. It make all columns editable.

   this.gridApi.startEditingCell()

But issue is even if I click any row below current editing row then my editable row become non editable and my action column still show save and cancel. Now I do not know how to change the cell renderer of a column when row become non editable or how to prevent this action

Comment: someone please help me in that issue.

Comment: [Angular Data Grid: Cell Editors](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/cell-editors/). Check the second last `dynamic parameters` example. When you change the country, the city column also changes. Also, if possible try creating a working example on codesandbox or other online code editor.

Comment: Are you using cellEditor or cellRenderer ?
I will suggest you to use cellRenderer with editable: true inside cellRendererParams .

Comment: I am using cell editor. I have created own component for cell editor for both the drop downs

Comment: I got you, it is same what i was thinking .. you are using custom components and then by registering them into frameworkComponents, you are using them with columnDefs.. for more info please check the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to use `cellRenderer` with `editable: true` inside `cellRendererParams` .

This will resolve the issue of becoming previous row non-editable while clicking on another row or outside the grid as in this state all of grid row's will be behave as editable.

And to manage your action items i think it's better to manage them by comparing the previous rowData and updated rowData.

If you will use the `cellEditor` with `cellEditorParams` then the issue of non-editable row will come in the picture as in this case you can make only single row editable at a point of time.

Please let me know if i can help you further in this .
Thank you.